# How to generate eclipse project from maven with "Maven Dependencies" instead of "Referenced Libraries" "M2_REPO/.."

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

How can I generate eclipse project from maven like :

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

but I need to get .classpath file like this :

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

instead of having all dependencies from pom like this :

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0-sources.jar">
<attributes>
  <attribute value="jar:file:/home/tr/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0-javadoc.jar!/" name="javadoc_location"/>
</attributes>
```

....

Comment: You should use m2e instead calling maven-eclipse-plugin from command line with `eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: I know how to get my project working with "org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER" but I want a maven plugin to generate the right .classpath for me, instead of working around by eclipse:clean and import existing maven project from eclipse.

Comment: Import the project into eclipse as Maven project will work...Which version of m2e do you use and which Eclipse version do you use? Apart from that which version of the maven-eclipse-plugin do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is conflicting M2E and mvn eclipse classpath entries. If you run eclipse:eclipse as well, then you will see referenced libraries added to your classpath.

The way to import is to run mvn eclipse:clean only on your project from a command line first and then import as maven project using eclipse M2E maven plugin to see maven dependencies "without referenced libraries". Otherwise, you will end up doing Maven -> Update project or remove "referenced libraries" manually from all your maven modules.